# Задержки при записи с камеры rtsp потока

Tags: linux, ubuntu, видео, rtsp

Имею цифровую  камеру Dahua  с которой хочу писать видео с rtsp потока на хост машину (Linux ubuntu server) . Использую openRTSP , уже написан скрипт для работы, контроля и т.д. . Я в цикле  запускаю запись и в параметрах передаю имя файла (текущее время и дата) . При старте записи идёт задержка 5 сек. на получение параметров от камеры и установки соединения . Но если пробросить порт на эту машину и запустить такую-же запись с другого хоста - то задержки нет.
И вот вопрос - почему есть задержка и как от неё избавиться ?

Comment: Под записью с другого хоста вы имеете в виду приём того же потока на другой хост?

Comment: Да . Причину уже нашол - Netfilter .